# Tkinter optionmenu

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, optionmenu

Is there a way to get the choice of an OptionMenu, without knowing the name of the StringVar the choice is saved in?

I have an function that automatically creates more OptionMenu items, and gives their variable the same name. It also saves the OptionMenu object in a list:

```
def addInternalPartipantList():
    global coworkerDict
    global f

    choiceVar1 = StringVar(window)
    choiceVar1.set('Vælg medarbejder')
    coworkerChoice = OptionMenu(window, choiceVar1, *coworkerDict)
    f += 1
    coworkerChoice.grid(column = 2, row = f)
    chosenCoworkers.append(coworkerChoice)
```

Now can I do something like:

```
chosenCoworkers[0].getVar().get()
```

to get the chosen coworker in that specific OptionMenu?

or is there another way that I can specify which `choiceVar1` it is that I want to get the value of?

The function is called by a Button, if that has any relevance for the answer to this question

Comment: You can use a command argument in the OptionMenu to send the selected value to a function.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I'm not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: Why don't you save the `StringVar`s to `chosenCoworkers`, then use `chosenCoworkers[0].get()` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of how you can check a value when someone selects the item.

When you use a command to reference a function in the OptionsMenu method the command will automatically pass the value selected as the event. This way you can actually do something with that value without even knowing the StringVar.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk() 

def print_choice(event):
    print(choice_var.get()) # prints value based on choice var
    print(event)# prints selection directly from the event passed by the command in OptionMenu

working_list = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"]
choice_var = tk.StringVar()
tk.OptionMenu(root, choice_var, *working_list, command=print_choice).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Here is another example. No mater how many OptionsMenu you create if you set the command to a function you can always get the value selected without knowing the StringVar.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk() 

def print_choice(event):
    print(event)# prints selection directly from the event passed by the command in OptionMenu

working_list = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"]

for i in range(4):
    tk.OptionMenu(root, tk.StringVar(), *working_list, command=print_choice).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Great answer, but I have question to it. Would you then save the choices in the list chosenCoworker at the time of the event? or will I be able to go back and check at a later point what the values are of each choice?

Comment: @T.Aalbaek You could simply apply the value to a global variable at the time of event. I think that would be better.

Comment: Yeah. But that would mean that I would need to declare a potentially infinite amount of variables that I could assign the values to. Or am I misunderstanding you? 'Cause at the end of the program the user will press a button and all the information is distributed to different places, like word documents and mail software and others. Whereafter the program terminates.

Comment: @T.Aalbaek: You could make the `command` argument be a `lambda` function that passed the `StringVar` to the associated function instead of, or in addition, to the value that it was set to. That way it would be easy to collect all the information and avoid the use of global variables.

Comment: Mike: I was going to up-vote your answer because I didn't know `OptionMenu`s had a `command` option, but then I saw your comment recommending the use of global variables and decided not it.

Comment: @martineau Yes typically I do not recommend global but it can be used if you are not building in a class. Also this is one of my older post. Probably before I was fully into OOP.

Comment: In the context of the OP's code, which is already using them, and your explanation, I excuse you. ;¬)